# GRAILS 3.1.0 not showing Bootstrap glyphicons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tomcat, grails

I am using bootstrap on a GRAILS 3.1.0 application with

```
compile 'org.webjars:bootstrap:3.3.6'
```

When I run the app both dev and prod from grails ...

```
grails prod run-app
grails dev run-app
```

... all work propertly, both bootstap components and glyphicons, but when I put the war on a Tomcat, the glyphicons are not shown, but the bootstrap components works propertly.

I have seen some errors on traces with the form

```
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/helloworldapplication/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf] in DispatcherServlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'
```

The files could be found on Tomcat in the folder

```
webapps\helloworldapplication\assets\webjars\bootstrap\3.3.6\fonts
```

This happends in Grails 3.1.0 and 3.1.1

Answer (score 0):

I got the same trouble yesterday. I tried to copy *fonts* during the *war packaging phase* at the right place, but it didn't work. 
I figured it out by just redirecting the request to the right path. To do so, first, I made an **interceptor** to catch the request and to redirect it :

```
class BootstrapInterceptor {

    int order = HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE
    String bootstrapVersion = null

    public BootstrapInterceptor() {
        match(uri: "/fonts/**")
    }

    boolean before() {
        if(bootstrapVersion == null) {
            setBootstrapVersion(request)
        }

        def to = "/assets/webjars/bootstrap/${bootstrapVersion}${request.getRequestURI()}"
        log.debug("Redirect: ${request.getRequestURI()} to: $to")
        redirect(uri: to)
        false
    }

    boolean after() { true }

    void afterView() {
        // no-op
    }

    private void setBootstrapVersion(def request) {
        def path = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/")
        def bootstrapSubFolders = new File("${path}assets/webjars/bootstrap/").listFiles()

        if (bootstrapSubFolders?.length == 1) {
            bootstrapVersion = bootstrapSubFolders[0].name
            log.debug("Bootstrap version detected: $bootstrapVersion")
        }
        else if (bootstrapSubFolders?.length > 1) {
            bootstrapVersion = bootstrapSubFolders[0].name
            log.warn("Multiple versions of bootstrap detected, taking $bootstrapVersion")
        }
        else {
            log.warn("Unable to catch the bootstrap version")
            bootstrapVersion = ""
        }
    }
}
```

You need to tell to Grails to allow requests like */fonts/whatever*. Without that, the interceptor won't be called. So, the little trick is to put that line on the **UrlMappings**:

```
"/fonts/**"(redirect: '/intercepted/by/bootstrap/interceptor')
```

And it should work (with your tomcat and without, and even if you upgrade your bootstrap version !). 
With that method, you should not have a *fonts* folder inside you webapp (because it will be redirected to the bootstrap fonts folder).

Hope it helps you ;)

PS : if you don't want to make it as an interceptor, you can change your tomcat url mapping to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of asset pipeline , the plugin manages the resource itself so it would also help to follow the convention. 
Seems you have the fonts folder inside the bootstrap folder, on your application create the fonts folder inside the assets folder and rest should work by itself.

Answer (score 0):

I put my glyphicon font files inside /grails-app/assets/fonts/. Then, from [here](https://www.technologyscout.net/2015/07/adding-assets-in-grails-3/), I did this:

> Put the fonts directory parallel to stylesheets, images and javascript
>   into the grails-app/assets/ folder. For the asset pipeline to know the
>   new directory, specify it in the build.gradle file:
>
> ```
> assets {
>     minifyJs = true
>     minifyCss = true
>     includes = ["fonts/*"]
> }
> ```

Then, it seems I also had to do a `grails clean` before the glyph icons showed up.